# Back propagation for neural network ( Error in shapes )

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, conv-neural-network

Below I attached 4 pictures with error as a picture.

Generally, I'm training my neural network ( having a **`2, 3, 1`** architecture ) that consists of two input neurons in the input layer, 3 neurons in my hidden layer and 1 output neuron in my output layer.

So, I trained my network using back propagation and I am having small error ( which is specified in the picture ).

Can someone help me with that please.

> `Error: shapes (200,200) and (1,3) not aligned: 200 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0)`

```
import numpy as np

import random

# Generating training data set according to the function y=x^2+y^2
input1_train = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(200,))
input2_train = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(200,))
input1_sq_train= input1_train **2
input2_sq_train= input2_train **2
input_merge= np.column_stack((input1_train,input2_train))
# normalized input data
input_merge= input_merge / np.amax(input_merge, axis=0)
# output of the training data
y_output_train= input1_sq_train + input2_sq_train
# normalized output data
y_output_train= y_output_train / 100

# Generating test data set according to the function y=x^2+y^2
input1_test = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(100,))
input2_test = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(100,))
input1_sq_test= input1_test **2
input2_sq_test= input2_test **2
y_output_test= input1_sq_test + input2_sq_test
# Merging two inputs of testing data into an one matrix
input_merge1= np.column_stack((input1_test,input2_test))
# normalized input test data
input_merge1=input_merge1 / np.amax(input_merge1, axis=0)
# normalized output test data
y_output_test= y_output_test / 100


# Generating validation data set according to the function y=x^2+y^2
input1_validation = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(50,))
input2_validation = np.random.uniform(low=-1, high=1, size=(50,))
input1_sq_validation= input1_validation **2
input2_sq_validation= input2_validation **2
input_merge2= np.column_stack((input1_validation,input2_validation))
# normalized input validation data
input_merge2= input_merge2 / np.amax(input_merge2, axis=0)
y_output_validation= input1_sq_validation + input2_sq_validation
# normalized output validation data
y_output_validation= y_output_validation / 100

class Neural_Network(object):

  def __init__(self):
     # parameters
     self.inputSize = 2
     self.outputSize = 1
     self.hiddenSize = 3

     # weights
     self.W1 = np.random.randn(self.inputSize,  self.hiddenSize) # (3x2)
     # weight matrix from input to hidden layer
     self.W2 = np.random.randn(self.hiddenSize, self.outputSize) # (3x1) 
     # weight matrix from hidden to output layer

  def forward(self, input_merge):
     # forward propagation through our network
     self.z = np.dot(input_merge, self.W1) # dot product of X (input) and first set of 3x2 weights
     self.z2 = self.sigmoid(self.z) # activation function
     self.z3 = np.dot(self.z2, self.W2) # dot product of hidden layer (z2) 
     # and second set of 3x1 weights
     o = self.sigmoid(self.z3) # final activation function
     return o

  def costFunction(self, input_merge, y_output_train):
     # Compute cost for given X,y, use weights already stored in class.
     self.o = self.forward(input_merge)
     J = 0.5*sum((y_output_train-self.yHat)**2)
     return J

  def costFunctionPrime(self, input_merge, y_output_train):
     # Compute derivative with respect to W and W2 for a given X and y:
     self.o = self.forward(input_merge)

     delta3 = np.multiply(-(y_output_train-self.yHat), 
                            self.sigmoidPrime(self.z3))
     dJdW2 = np.dot(self.a2.T, delta3)

     delta2 = np.dot(delta3, self.W2.T)*self.sigmoidPrime(self.z2)
     dJdW1 = np.dot(input_merge.T, delta2)  

     return dJdW1, dJdW2

  def sigmoid(self, s):
     # activation function 
     return 1/(1+np.exp(-s))

  def sigmoidPrime(self, s):
     # derivative of sigmoid
     return s * (1 - s)

  def backward(self, input_merge, y_output_train, o):
     # backward propgate through the network
     self.o_error = y_output_train - o                # error in output
     self.o_delta = self.o_error*self.sigmoidPrime(o) # applying  derivative of sigmoid to error

     self.z2_error = self.o_delta.dot(self.W2.T)      # z2 error: how much our hidden layer weights contributed to output error
     self.z2_delta = self.z2_error*self.sigmoidPrime(self.z2) # applying derivative of sigmoid to z2 error

     self.W1 += input_merge.T.dot(self.z2_delta)      # adjusting first set (input --> hidden) weights
     self.W2 += self.z2.T.dot(self.o_delta)           # adjusting second set (hidden --> output) weights

  def train (self, input_merge, y_output_train):
     o = self.forward(input_merge)
     self.backward(input_merge, y_output_train, o)

NN = Neural_Network()

for i in range(1000): # trains the NN 1,000 times

    #  print (   "Actual Output for training data: \n" + str(y_output_train))
    #  print ("Predicted Output for training data: \n" +  str(NN.forward(input_merge)))

    print ( "Loss for training: \n"
          +  str( np.mean( np.square( y_output_train
                                    - NN.forward( input_merge )
                                      )
                           )
                  )
             ) # mean sum squared loss
    NN.train(input_merge, y_output_train)

# NN.test(input_merge1,y_output_test)
# NN.validation(input_merge2,y_output_validation)
```

Comment: Seems like you misformatted your message. Could you edit it to include the images themselves, instead of the links to them? Also, the title could be more clear - right now it sounds as generic as it could.

Comment: It's better if you post a code block with the code snippet instead of a picture. In addition, the picture doesn't contain the error you describe above

Answer (score 0):

*"Having small error"* is actually a major issue on mat/vec-dimensions:

---

So, first, it is a fair practice to post MCVE-based formulation of Stack Overflow presented problems.

Here, that would mean to also copy the complete Error-Traceback, including the row numbers, where the Traceback has been thrown. OK, you will get it right next time.

Your problem is not a *small error* -- your code is principally wrong, as it tries ( at an unknown location ) to process a pair of arrays, that do not match in shape for a yet unknown operation ( it just seems that a `.multiply()` is the right suspect, but not sure, where it could get called, as there is no clear request to ask for a `.costFunctionPrime()` method ).

Nevertheless, an attempt was done, somewhere, to process the pair of matrix/vector arrays, one, being **`[200,200]`**, the other, being **`[1,3]`** simply do not make their processing possible.

So, the error is in your code / syntax. Check it, possibly using a pre-printed shape-checks:

```
def aFormatSHAPE( anArray ):
    return "[{0: >4d},{1: >4d}]".format( anArray.shape[0],
                                         anArray.shape[1]
                                         )

def aHelperPrintSHAPE( anArray1, anArray2 ):
    try:
        print( "CHK:{0:}-(op)-{1:}".format( aFormatSHAPE( anArray1 ),
                                            aFormatSHAPE( anArray2 )
                                            )
                )
    except:
        pass
    return
```

Once you repair your code so that it meets all the common matrix-vector algebra rules ( on how additions, subtractions, multiplications, dot-products are processed on arrays/vectors ), then your small error is solved.

You should never see anything like:

```
CHK:[200,200]-(op)-[1,3]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me your matrix dimensions don't fit. You cannot multiply (200,200) with (1,3). No. of columns of first matrix must match no. of rows of second matrix in simple terms. Hope this helps.